# Can we use "saccade" as a verb to describe eye movements

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, word-usage

*Saccade* is the term to describe rapid eye movements. I just want to be sure that *saccading* could be used as a verb, or if not, which term would you recommend using?

Comment: _Saccade_ is a noun. It's mostly something you count, so it's normally reported as being made or occurring. Since saccades are very frequent and unconscious, they're not noticeable. A _twitch_, on the other hand, **is** noticeable, and therefore rare, thus not the same thing.

Comment: Do you really _need_ a verb? What is the sentence you want to write?

Comment: ... though of course any, absolutely any English word can be used as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend ***twitch***. *Saccade* is a noun with *saccadic* being the corresponding adjective. There is no prevalent verb form.

Example sentence from dicitonary:

> *He gets a twitch in his left eye when he's nervous.*

Another term (admittedly rare even for medical professionals) is ***vellicate*** , basically [meaning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vellicate) to twitch.

Comment: But we are talking about eye movements, isn't twitch more generic?

Comment: I agree with @Leon: If the question is about eye movements, then twitch is not correct, because it is too general. In addition, twitch typically applies to muscle movements, not eye movements.

Comment: Oops - I might have to consult some references again!!! I was not aware that eyes could move independent of muscles...and guess what - both your assertions are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saccade) lists a verb form for saccade:

> **saccade** (third-person singular simple present saccades, present participle saccading, simple past and past participle saccaded)
>
> (of the eye) To make a rapid jerking movement to focus elsewhere.

However, in the academic literature on eye movements, **saccade** is almost always used as a noun. (For whatever reason, I have not encountered **saccading** and find it a little odd.) To use saccade as a verb in this literature, one often uses a verb phrase construction like **make a saccade**:

> Subjects were instructed to fixate a central target and then make a saccade to one of three targets after hearing an acoustic stimulus. After making the saccade, another stimulus would sound indicating success on the trial.

Comment: Quite apart from the fact that twitches (including saccades) can be both voluntary and involuntary, there are too many factual errors in this post to merit individual listing and extreme caution is advised.

Comment: @user49727 I appreciate the feedback and have removed what I hope are the objectionable parts of my post (trying to differentiate twitch and saccade). Hopefully the eye movement literature isn't *so* different from the medical literature!?